# How to fix ./configure command does not exist error on ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: command-line

I was installing tar.bz2 application (OpenFM) on my Ubuntu 14.10 and I followed steps listed on this website: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/compile-install-tar-gz-tar-bz2-files-ubuntu-linux/ .

When I had to run the "./configure" command I saw this:

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

On this website there were a note if my system does not have the ./configure command I can skip to the next chapter of the guide what contained executing "make" command.

When I executed "make" command without executing "./configure" command I saw this:

```
make: *** * ***No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Please answer to me how to fix this error or how to install .tar.bz2 application without "./configure" command.

Sorry for my terrible English and thanks for help!

Comment: The conclusion is that there is no file `./configure` in the downloaded` tar (I checked also). The instructions seem to be incorrect. Did you manage somehow?

Answer (score 0):

`configure` is a script (file) located in the source tree of a source distribution.
Check if it exists in the source tree of OpenFM and that is it executable.

Comment: I checked and it has no file such as **configure**. Maybe it's hidden or something and here it is to download from Mega: (https://mega.co.nz/#!T1pGALDQ!JvEO_7TRMKFnv8pfb1BLFELakDH5HKVsJOoIJK8HkU0) If you help me with this i will be very grateful =).